# Gimp Tools Bugged

Tags: gimp

my some of my tools not working anymore like I can change their settings like size or shape but they're not actually drawing anything its like drawing transparent and  the brush cursor stuck at the place i try to draw there for the second i click 
tools that have this problem (pencil, brush, airbrush, eraser, clone tool)
how ever i still can select thing and use other tools like bucket tool

[image]

I tried reinstalling gimp in other directions but that did not fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, and reinstalling GIMP won't fix it.

From your screenshot I can see the problem. The layer you have selected is hidden, and another potential problem is that the top layer is visible and is therefore covering the selected layer below.

- To edit a layer in GIMP it must be visible. You must enable the "eye" icon in the layers panel for the layer you are trying to edit, or select a layer that is already visible, otherwise those tools won't work
- The layer you are editing must be active. To do that, click on the layer in the layers panel.
- If layers above are covering the layer you are trying to edit, you
  may not be able to see anything you edit on the layers below. You may need to temporarily hide any layers above to be able to see what you are doing.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot but i already knew that just somehow manage to fix the problem by using these buttons in Tool Options menu                                                                                                    https://ibb.co/FxYz3MM